# How to extract header properties when using routes

Tags: routes, apache-camel, talend

I'm new to Apache camel, routes and AMQP, I'm sending message to the broker like that :

[image]

When I show my request in Active MQ, I found the properties that I set in the header of my request message : [image]

I want to know how to extract the header from the message in order to forward it to my talend job.
I extract the body of the message using ($in.body) but the ($in.header) does not work.

[image]
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's using Camel's simple expression language then try with `${in.headers}` or if you would like to access a specific header then you can use `${in.header.something}`.

You can find more examples [here](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html).

### UPDATE

Working solution (from the comments): `${header.taskID}`

Comment: I tried both but it doesn't work :( ${in.headers} is not recognised

Comment: Does it work with for example `${header.taskID}`? (without the `in.` prefix)